# Definite article for things with a name/label

Tags: definite-article, nouns

In an article I describe a series of items with their name:

> ***ExtractionCommand***: Extraction command is used to extract data from the matching node.

Should I write it as:

> ***ExtractionCommand***: ***ExtractionCommand*** is used to extract data from the matching node.
>
> ***ExtractionCommand***: the ***ExtractionCommand*** is used to extract data from the matching node.
>
> ***ExtractionCommand***: The extraction command is used to extract data from the matching node.

However it is a name, but in the sentence I tried to use it as a compound noun, but don't know if I can/should do that or not! and if it needs *the*?

Extraction command is a simple command like

- `Include`
- `Exclude`
- `Include as story`

It tells the algorithm to include or exclude the content of a node in/from the output... or use a tag (story) for them...

Comment: Can you describe what ExtractionCommand is? For example, is it a procedure, or a command that causes a procedure to be executed, or an abstract concept?

Comment: @JavaLatte I added some description to the question.

Comment: So if we understand correctly, ExtractionCommand is the name for a *set* of possible commands, not just one particular command, right?

Comment: What @stangdon said. Your question makes it seem to be a type of command, not a single named command. Is it a setting that might typically be represented with an enum? ExtractionCommand.Include, ExtractionCommand.Exclude, ExtractionCommand.IncludeAsStory?

Comment: @stangdon right

Comment: @tromano it has a syntax. The command name is either include or exclude. Then an optional label after "as" keyword. There are other options  though.

Comment: So there is more than one command that could be called an extraction command.  In your case, then, Extraction Command is a type or category of command.  You could say ExtractionCommands in the plural. I think **an** extraction command would be clearest. Use an extraction command to extract data.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest option would be:

> *ExtractionCommand*: used to extract data from the matching node.

There's no need to repeat ExtractionCommand in any form.

Comment: Thanks that's a good option too. But l also like to learn if an article is needed....

Answer (score 1):

From the information that you have provided, it seems that an extraction command is the name of a non-finite set of possible commands, for example **include this** or **exclude that**.

You should therefore use an indefinite article to describe what an ExtractionCommand does:

> ExtractionCommand: **an** ExtractionCommand is used to extract data from the matching node.

Comment: +1 for the answer **an** extraction command, although I don't find the cow example very clear.

Comment: Can it be "an extraction command" too?